# Problema com o pandas no pycharm

Tags: pandas, pycharm

Estou usando o pandas pra importar um arquivo excel, entretanto, aparece o seguinte erro:

> Cannot find reference 'read_excel' in 'pandas.py'

```
import pandas as pd

dados = pd.read_excel(C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/ArtigosTCC/excel/didaticatech)
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o porque?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Everton, bom dia! Esse caminho que você está passando dentro do read_excel está correto? Pois você deveria apontar para o arquivo xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

Para chamar um arquivo é necessário colocar a referência como string (entre aspas) e explicitar o tipo do arquivo após o nome do mesmo:

```
dados = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/ArtigosTCC/excel/didaticatech.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

O `python` é uma linguagem `POO`, logo ele possui um conceito chamado `polimorfismo`, isso faz com que caso eu tenha uma função `something(self)` eu possa ter a mesma função `something(self)` com um parametro amais, ex: `something(self, other)`.

Quando você chama `pd.read_excel()` ele vai procurar no `pandas.py` pelo função `read_excel()`, por padrão ele irá pedir uma `string`, em python toda string fica entre *aspas* ou simples, ou compostas, se você colocar sem `strings` ele não reconhece e procura no `pandas.py` algumas outra função com o mesmo nome dela que receba parâmetros que não seja `strings`, com isso ela não encontra e retorna:

> Cannot find reference 'read_excel' in 'pandas.py'

Para resolver isso, coloque o caminho entre aspas simples ou compostas, ficaria assim:

```py
import pandas as pd

dados = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/ArtigosTCC/excel/didaticatech')
```

Ou com aspas compostas:

```py
import pandas as pd

dados = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/ArtigosTCC/excel/didaticatech")
```